# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - cannot find module "hapi"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hapi.js

I have a NodeJs application that I am trying to host on Elastic Beanstalk. I copied the structure of the example application but I get a health status of *Severe* on my server and the logs tell me `cannot find module 'hapi'`.

The steps I took are simple. The contents of my root folder are...

```
|__ package-lock.json
|__ package.json
|__ server.js
|__ src (directory)
```

The contents of my `package.json` is...

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "boom": "^7.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "hapi": "^17.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.11",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

The next thing I did was to compress the contents into a zip file. I *uploaded and deployed* the zip file on Elastic Beanstalk, and after all that, I get the error messages listed above.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? When I run `npm install` locally, everything looks like it should run. I'm assuming it is failing when the EB attempts to install the packages but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have saved the majority of your dependencies as `devDependencies` which means they are not available to the runtime in production. `devDependencies` are modules that are required during development, while dependencies are required at runtime.

This happens when you run `npm install package --save-dev` and not `npm install package --save`

Pretty sure you want most of these in dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "boom": "^7.2.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "hapi": "^17.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.11",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  }
```

and only the modules you need for local dev environment in:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
  }
```

take a quick review of what you actually need for the runtime in production and update your `dependencies`

Comment: Looks like, by default, Elastic Beanstalk runs `npm install --production`. If you want to install `devDependencies`, you can set the `NPM_USE_PRODUCTION` environment variable to **false**. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-packagejson.html)